# Can I have a .net 4.0 subdomain of a .net 3.5sp1 website?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I am maintaining a .net 3.5sp1 website. I'd like to upgrade a part of the site to 4.0 so I can start converting to SilverLight 4.0 & RIA services.

Can I create a subdomain of my main site, and have the subdomain be running 4.0 while the main website runs 3.5?

Answer (score 4):

4.0 uses a new runtime.  That means the two sections of your site are in different app domains, and *that* means certain things like Session and authentication tokens won't carry over well.  It doesn't mean you can't do it, but there will be some challenges to overcome.

Comment: FYI, you can also do it with two virtual directories in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean subdomain as in:

`http://aaaaa.yourdomain.com` and `http://bbbbb.yourdomain.com`

then yes, there's no reason at all why not.

Assuming you're using Windows Server 2003 or later, and IIS, [host header](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/)s let you run multiple web sites at a single IP address, and you can specify the version of the runtime to be used for each one independently.

I run Windows Server 2003 with about 20 separate sites on it, all subdomains of a single domain, and they're a mixture of ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0.

You specify the runtime version for each site in IIS manager, under `Web site > Properties > ASP.NET version`.  Not sure if it's exactly the same in Windows Server 2008, but it can't be all that different.